# iTerm2 closing curly brace not working

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, iterm2

in the last weeks I had the problem that in iTerm2 the closing curly brace is not working anymore.
It works in all other applications (including Terminal), but iTerm2 is not showing the curly brace. The opening curly brace works.

I have got a German keyboard, so it should be ALT+9

I uninstalled the shell integration, because I thought this problem occurs since the installation of the integration, but no success so far.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only seemed to be an issue in the test releases. The stable release doesn't have this issue

Comment: I have the same problem with Build 3.0.10

Answer (score 8):

For me it turns out the right ALT key works but not the left and it's because the left ALT key had a different setting.

You can change this by going to *Preferences -> Profiles -> Keys* and changing from **Esc+** to **Normal**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue using iTerm2 3.1.6 and a German keyboard layout.

In my case, it was caused by the option ***To switch split planes:*** being set to *⌥ Number*). This option can be found in *Preferences* > *Keys* > *Navigation Shortcuts*.

Any other setting for this option works as a workaround for the issue.

Comment: I spent a bit of time trying to understand the problem on my french keyboard layout, and that was it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem, and have been experiencing the same thing since I started using iterm/zsh in October 2016. It happens on both my work laptop and on my own personal laptop (I have almost exactly the same setup for both). This is only a problem in iterm - the regular mac OS terminal works just fine.

I'm currently using iterm build 3.1.5. and also have a German keyboard layout.

It's annoying, but I recently found out that `CTRL + ALT + 9` does the job.

I would be interested to know of a proper fix.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very nice workaround, but I only got it to work by adding the curly braces as shortcuts:

1. Go to Preferences → Keys → Key Mappings
2. Make sure there are no conflicting mappings
3. Add two new key mappings for opening/closing curly braces: The shortcut is the key combination for getting the braces, the action is "Send text", and the value is the curly brace